Can I detect multiple ids with Amazon Textract using Identity Documents?
I have this passport type document, the idea is to be able to obtain the data from it, but I am currently having a problem.
The passport number that I am obtaining is not what I expected, because instead of taking No.Passport from the image, it is returning identity No.
I leave the image so that you can guide yourself, also an image of my logs from my console.enter image description here
enter image description here
I would like to have the possibility of obtaining both numbers, however, I was reading the Amazon documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/how-it-works-identity.html and it seems to be limited.
private Map<String,Object> extractDocumentIdentify(SpecialDocument specialDocument, Document document) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    String key = "";
    String value = "";
    List<String> faildsKeys = null;

    List<Document> listDocument = new ArrayList<>();
    listDocument.add(document);

    AnalyzeIdRequest idRequest = AnalyzeIdRequest.builder().documentPages(listDocument).build();

    AnalyzeIdResponse responseAnalyze = specialDocument.getTextractAsyncClient().analyzeID(idRequest).get();
    List<IdentityDocument> docs = responseAnalyze.identityDocuments();
    for (IdentityDocument doc : docs) {
        key   = "";
        value = "";


        List<IdentityDocumentField> idFields = doc.identityDocumentFields();
        logger.info("IdentityDocuments => "+ idFields);
        for (IdentityDocumentField field : idFields) {

            key = field.type().text();
            value = field.valueDetection().text();
            logger.info("Key => "+ key);
            logger.info("Value => "+ value);
            if( validFields.containsKey(key) ){

                if(!Objects.equals(value,"")){
                    value = StringUtils.formatDate(value);
                }
                if(value.isBlank()){
                    if (faildsKeys == null) faildsKeys = new ArrayList<>();
                        faildsKeys.add(key);
                    }
                }

                if( key.equals("FIRST_NAME") && value.isBlank()){
                    if (faildsKeys == null) faildsKeys = new ArrayList<>();
                    faildsKeys.add("name");
                }

                result.put(StringUtils.toCamelCase(field.type().text()), value);
            }
        }
        if(faildsKeys != null && faildsKeys.size()>0) {
            analyzeDoc(specialDocument, document, faildsKeys, result);
        }
    return result;
}

